# how to remove u letter and quotaion from a table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I do not know how to remove u letter and single quotation in the table.
the value of column:

```
[u'south', u'st', u'standing', u'supervisors', u'suspended', u'sw', u'title=link', u'transportation', u'transporting', u'trips', u'vary', u'weather']
```

Can anyone help me about that? thanks

Comment: I worked out the problem. using update jobs_tmp set term_map = replace(term_map, 'u''','');  thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem. the sql statement as following:

```
update jobs_tmp set term_map = regexp_replace(term_map, '\mu''','', 'gi')
```